# Getting file name from URL in php

Tags: php

I need to get the name of the file from url

```
$url = 'http://p1.pichost.me/i/53/1770973.jpg'

$fileName = getFileName($url);
```

is there some php function to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `basename()` in this case:

```
$url = 'http://p1.pichost.me/i/53/1770973.jpg';
$filename = basename($url);
echo $filename; // 1770973.jpg
```